# How to track branching records on a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, ranking-functions

Example, there are machines that processes and produced materials, is there a way to track the output of machine becoming the input of another, and counting how many passes the process took? here is the example desired output (pass column):

| Record# | machine | input | output | pass | material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 40422041 | 40422041 | 1 | ABC74008000 |
| 2 | 2 | 40422041 | 40422041 | 2 | ABC74004200 |
| 3 | 3 | 40422041 | 40422041 | 3 | ABC74002100 |
| 4 | 4 | 40422041 | A40422041 | **4** | ABC74001200 |
| 5 | 4 | 40422041 | 40422041 | 4 | ABC74001200 |
| 6 | 5 | 40422041 | M421200629 | 5 | ABC73000660 |
| 7 | 6 | A40422041 | M521200827 | **5** | ABC73000660 |
| 8 | 6 | A40422041 | M521220239 | **6** | ABC73000660 |

notice records 1,2,3,5 & 6 = these are all coming from input 40422041.
records 4,7 & 8 are results of A40422041 which was an output of 40422041, thus the pass is needed to be 4 on record # 4, and continued as pass 5 and 6 on records 7 & 8.

How can the pass sequence be achieved?

Comment: `records 1,2,3,5 & 6 = these are all coming from input 40422041` Why `record 4` is excluded?

Comment: In T-SQL you may want to look into graph objects https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-sample?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Squirrel - yeah just to highlight the scenario that on records 4 & 5, they run on the same machine with the same input and the output SPLIT into 2 thus they have the same pass

Comment: How do you count the `pass` ? How do you determine which is the first pass ?